# add a column and compute total score for cases that have at least 4 responses

Tags: r, function, lapply, sapply

How would you go about computing the same by using only R functions lapply( ), sapply( ), etc.?

## Add a column (anxiety) to hold the total score

`likert.scale.matrix <- cbind(scale.matrix.2, rep(NA, dim(scale.matrix.2)[1]))`

```
dimnames(likert.scale.matrix) <- list(id = (mydata.clean$id),
                               c("general", "affective", "cognitive", "value", "difficulty", "anxiety"))

<!-- html table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package -->
<!-- Sun Feb 22 14:44:01 2015 -->
<table border=1>
<tr> <th>  </th> <th> general </th> <th> affective </th> <th> cognitive </th> <th> value </th> <th> difficulty </th> <th> anxiety </th>  </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 3 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 5.00 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 21.00 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 34 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td align="right"> 12.00 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 40 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 15.00 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 66 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 3.00 </td> <td align="right"> 16.00 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 67 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td align="right"> 12.00 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

## compute total score for cases that have at least 4 responses

```
for(i in 1:dim(likert.scale.matrix)[1]){
    n <- 0 # number of responses
    sum <- 0 # total statistics anxiety

    for (j in 1:dim(likert.scale.matrix)[2]){
         if(!is.na(likert.scale.matrix[i,j])){
            # calculate total statistics anxiety
            sum <- sum + likert.scale.matrix[i,j]
            # increment number of responses
            n <- n+1
         }
    }

    # if the number of responses is 4 or more score is given
    if(n >= 4) {likert.scale.matrix[i, 6] <- sum}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why use lapply or sapply?

You should really be using

```
s <- sum(likert.scale.matrix, na.rm = TRUE)
n <- sum(!is.na(likert.scale.matrix))
```

Comment: I was hoping not to use use any loops and take advantage of R's vector oriented features but can't figure out how to put a constraint on the sum (if 4 out of 5 values is not NA, then calculate sum).

Comment: if(apply(likert.scale.matrix[,1:5], 1, count) >= 4){
likert.scale.matrix[, "anxiety"] <- apply(likert.scale.matrix[,1:5], 1, sum)
    }

Comment: apologies, the code I posted doesn't do what you need. If you rowSums(..., na.rm = TRUE) over the relevant columns, then times this by as.numeric(rowSums(lik... > 0, na.rm = TRUE)))